# How to add multilevel accordion in wordpress using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a multilevel accordion to my WordPress site. So I made a [**fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/xxd9cry4/) which is working good But in WordPress multilevel not working ! Only show the first level But multilevel is now showing. Please help.

I want to use [WordPress jQuery library](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and add the jQuery UI to my theme `function.php` so I add bellow code

```
function add_jquery_ui() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-accordion' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jquery_ui' );
```

Then I Add this code to my theme `footer.php` before `</body>` section

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(".lifetime-faq").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});

 $(function () {
     var icons = {
         header: "iconClosed",    // custom icon class
         activeHeader: "iconOpen" // custom icon class
     };
     $(".lifetime-faq").accordion({
         icons: icons
     });
 });
});
```

Comment: Any error in your console ?

Comment: I fix this there was a HTML markup error